# Tomcat on AWS ElasticBeanstalk doesn't Accept JSON

Tags: json, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services

I have written a spring MVC application using the spring tools for eclipse and deployed it onto an tomcat 7 environment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  But when I try to return JSON I get the following error.

```
 406- The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

But when I run the same application locally on glassfish server it runs perfectly and returns the intended json as follows:

```
 {"id":1,"message":"Hello, World!","description":"Hello, World!"}
```

Here is my code:

Controller code :

```
private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting",headers="Accept=*/*",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseBean greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name,HttpServletResponse response , ModelMap model){

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    return new ResponseBean(counter.incrementAndGet(),String.format(template, name),String.format(template, name));

}
```

My Response Bean Code :

```
package com.ramesh.beans;

public class ResponseBean {

    private final int id;
    private final String message;
    private final String description;

    public ResponseBean(int id,String message,String desc){
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.description = desc;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

My servlet-context.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ramesh.ws" />

</beans:beans>
```

Could anyone please help me out ?. I am willing to provide any more information about my program if needed.

My request headers on chrome are as follows :

They are as follows :

```
 1 requests ❘ 1.3 KB transferred ❘ 250 ms (load: 256 ms, DOMContentLoaded: 257 ms)
 HeadersPreviewResponseTiming
 Remote Address:54.206.99.113:80
 Request URL:http://ramesh-dev-gvssfipguk.elasticbeanstalk.com/greeting
 Request Method:GET
 Status Code:406 Not Acceptable
```

Request Headers

```
 Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
 Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4
 Cache-Control:max-age=0
 Connection:keep-alive
 Host:ramesh-dev-gvssfipguk.elasticbeanstalk.com
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like      Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers

```
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Length:1070
 Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
 Date:Tue, 20 May 2014 10:14:45 GMT
 Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
 X-Cache:MISS from tx33vspep22a
```

Comment: A 406 means that the Client\Browser sent an `Accepts` that the server could not provide.  Are you testing locally using the same mean (browser/etc) as when you test remotely?  I am not familiar with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I would venture a guess that there may be something in between the Tomcat instance and the web, like maybe an Apache web server.  It's possible that might be blocked.  Can you open up the debug tools in your browser and see what `Accepts` header is being sent?  Reference of HTTP Status codes:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Thanks CodeChimp for your quick reply. I used Google Chrome and checked the request headers.I have added them to my question.

Comment: I believe this is an issue with the tomcat server itself. Since this occurs when I try deploying the tomcat server locally as well.

Comment: Your request/response headers should be sending 'application/json'.  Can you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by updating my controller method as shown below:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting",produces="application/json",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseBean greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name,HttpServletResponse response , ModelMap model){

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    return new ResponseBean(counter.incrementAndGet(),String.format(template, name),String.format(template, name));

}
```

It seems when deploying to tomcat I need the produces="application/json" property.